# Circle that transforms to a box

Tags: javascript, html, css

i was wondering how to make a circle that transforms into a wider box in html/css.
I have tried this but it does not transform properly

If you guys have any ideas on how to make this, i would really appreaciate it very much thank you!

```
.circle{
    width: 700px;
    height:700px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: #14b1e7;
    animation-name: stretch;
    animation-duration:6s;
    animation-timing-function:ease-out;
    animation-delay:0s;
    animation-duration:alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-play-state: running;
    opacity: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 5px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 30px;
}




@keyframes stretch {
    0%{
        transform: scale(.1);
        background-color:#14b1e7;
        border-radius: 100%;
    }

    50%{
        background-color: #14b1e7;

    }

    100%{
        transform:scale(.7);
        background-color: #14b1e7;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what transforming into a wider box is? Do you mean it stays as a circle but gets larger until, say, it fills a rectangular box as much as possible, or do you want it to gradually change shape from a circle to a rectangle as it gets bigger?

Comment: Yep, exactly it stays as a circle for a bit then it fills a rectangular box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-https-yhtpoe?file=/src/styles.css

```
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.circle:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
```

In the example, the circle initially has 50% border-radius and 100px width. On hover, border-radius is set to 0 and width to 200px. Because of the `transition` property, the change is animated.

The `transition: all 1s` property makes every property change gradually and last for 1 second. Check the docs for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: Thanks, it helped but I was wondering how to make it do it without hover, for example it keeps the circle for 5s then it transforms to rectangular box and stays like that.

Comment: I have edited the live example according to your needs. The key changes are adding a `transition-delay` property to `.circle` in CSS and setting a class to each circle in Javascript that turns the circle into a box.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change `border-radius` according to the keyframes.

```css
.animation {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid #337ab7;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
  animation: circle-to-square 1s .83s infinite cubic-bezier(1,.015,.295,1.225) alternate;
}
 
@keyframes circle-to-square {
  0%  {
     border-radius:100% 100% 100% 100%;
    background:black;
   
  }
  25%  {
    border-radius:75% 75% 75% 75%;
    background:black;
   
  }
  50%  {
    border-radius:50% 50% 50% 50%;
    background:black;
   
  }
  75%  { 
  border-radius:25% 25% 25% 25%;
    background:black;
    
  }
  100% {  
    border-radius:0 0 0 0;
    background:black;
   
  }
```

```html
<div class="container animated zoomIn">
  <div class="row">
<div class="animation"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```